# Header not inheriting new margin or width set by class in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm new to working with CSS with HTML so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this problem. I'm currently creating a website and I'm trying to change the width and margin for all text in the `skill-row` class. The `<p>` text is inheriting this correctly but the `<h3>` is not. The `<h3>` tag does seem to be inheriting the new text alignment from center to left so I'm unsure what's going wrong.

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: #66BFBF;
}

h3 {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: #11999E;
}

.skill-row {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 100px auto 100px auto;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sacramento|Poppins|Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="skills">
  <h2>My Skills.</h2>
  <div class="skill-row">
    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/2460/2460376.png" alt="computer">
    <h3>Software Development</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quis in duis, iaculis id felis. Consectetuer vestibulum, nunc urna lectus, erat ligula. Hendrerit nam, lectus ante, ut lorem eros.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="skill-row">
    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/1635/1635475.png" alt="microphone">
    <h3>Classical Singing</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mauris sed consectetuer. Etiam et eu, bibendum interdum, lacus quis mauris. Curabitur wisi, quisque vel eu, rutrum nam.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what width have u defined for class 'skills' ? which is the parent for 'skill-row', this will change a lot of things in output.

Comment: it's because you have set the width to 75% and centred the whole h3 (even though the text is left aligned inside it) - if you don't want it centred then you need to give it a width of 100% or remove the margin auto

Comment: do you want the h3 align left? so remove margin: 0 auto; this rule is used to center.

Comment: Nothing has been defined yet for the skills class. According to what I see in the developer tools, the parent would be the body.

Comment: What kind of output do you want?

Comment: Also I have the h3 set to margin: 0 auto; because the h3 tag is used for other divs and most of them should be centered. It's only this class where I want it aligned left

Comment: Can you just give us a picture?

Comment: then either add a class to these h3 or quantify it with skill-row, eg: `.skill-row h3 {width:100% }`  - I think you may need to do a tutorial to learn css as this is very basic stuff

Comment: If you want to be more specific you have to overwrite  h3 like this `.skill-row h3{}`

Comment: The .skills-row h3 {} worked for me. Thanks!